# Creating grouped gridview and binding Observable collection data after grouping but no INotifyProperty Change is affecting the grid?

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, windows-8, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to make a grouped gridview in Windows 8 application I have a class named book whose ObservableCollection I have made in my ViewModel class for that page. But I need to group the data when I am trying to group and bind the data on my codebind file of XAML and then binding there is no effect of INotifyProperty happening. Please suggest how can I achieve this in my VW?

Code Below:

Code Behind of XAML:

```
 protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter,
                                               Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
            MainViewModel booksList = new MainViewModel();
            var teamGroups = booksList.BooksDetail.GroupBy(team => team.BookCategory)
                                           .OrderBy(team => team.Key.ToString());

            this.groupedItemsViewSource.Source = teamGroups;
        }
```

View Model Class:

```
  #region BooksDetail Collection
        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="BooksDetail" /> BooksDetail
        /// </summary>
        public const string BooksDetailPropertyName = "BooksDetail";

        private ObservableCollection<Book> _booksDetailProperty = new ObservableCollection<Book>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the BooksDetail property.
        /// TODO Update documentation:
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<Book> BooksDetail
        {
            get
            {
                return _booksDetailProperty;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_booksDetailProperty == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _booksDetailProperty = value;

                // Update bindings, no broadcast
                RaisePropertyChanged(BooksDetailPropertyName);
            }
        }
        #endregion

  public void GetBooksDetail()
        {

                try
                {
                    // Check if the code is in Design Mode or Running Mode
                    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
                    {
                        // Created the object of main model class
                        DesignMainModel mainModel = new DesignMainModel();

                        // Call method to get list of books detail
                        this.BooksDetail = mainModel.GetBooksDetailData();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Check for internet connectivity 
                        if (Utility.IsInternetAvailable())
                        {
                            //TODO: Write the logic to to implement in Running Mode
                            // Created the object of main model class
                            DesignMainModel mainModel = new DesignMainModel();

                            // Call method to get list of books detail
                            this.BooksDetail = mainModel.GetBooksDetailData();

                            // Group by data on Book Category
                            this.GroupByBookDetailsOnCategory();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Display Error Message for No internet Connection available
                            util.ShowUserMessage(App.GeneralMessageResource.GetString("InternetConnectionErrorMessage"), App.GeneralMessageResource.GetString("InternetConnectionErrorCategory"));
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Display the error
                    util.ShowUserMessage(ex.Message, App.GeneralMessageResource.GetString("GeneralErrorTitle"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Books Class:

```
   #region BookCategory Property
        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="BookCategory" /> property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string BookCategoryPropertyName = "BookCategory";

        /// <summary>
        /// The _book category property
        /// </summary>
        private string _bookCategoryProperty = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the BookCategory property.
        /// TODO Update documentation:
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
        /// </summary>
        public string BookCategory
        {
            get
            {
                return _bookCategoryProperty;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_bookCategoryProperty == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _bookCategoryProperty = value;

                // Update bindings, no broadcast
                RaisePropertyChanged(BookCategoryPropertyName);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Changed as per the input:
I have created an ObservableCollection of Tuple. But now when I am binding it to CollectionViewSource then no list is getting populated. Please refer the code below: Let me know where I am making mistake:

XAML:

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1"
         x:Name="itemGridView"
         SelectionMode="Multiple"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryLists}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
           ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CategoryListsStyle}">
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="0,-5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular" Foreground="#00bfff" FontSize="27"/>
                                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>-->
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,-1,35,0"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </GridView.GroupStyle>

</Grid>
```

Property:
    #region BooksDetailGrouped Collection
            /// 
            /// The  property's name.
            /// 
            public const string BooksDetailGroupedPropertyName = "BooksDetailGrouped";

```
        /// <summary>
        /// The _books detail grouped property
        /// </summary>
        private ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, ObservableCollection<Book>>> _booksDetailGroupedProperty = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, ObservableCollection<Book>>>();



        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the BooksDetailGrouped property.
        /// TODO Update documentation:
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, ObservableCollection<Book>>> BooksDetailGrouped
        {
            get
            {
                return _booksDetailGroupedProperty;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_booksDetailGroupedProperty == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _booksDetailGroupedProperty = value;

                // Update bindings, no broadcast
                RaisePropertyChanged(BooksDetailGroupedPropertyName);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Method to group:

```
// Grouping the data
            var booksGroup = this.BooksDetail.GroupBy(books => books.BookCategory)
                                            .OrderBy(books => books.Key.ToString());

            // Convert grouped data to ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, ObservableCollection<Book>>>
            this.BooksDetailGrouped = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, ObservableCollection<Book>>>(
            booksGroup.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Key,
                                            new ObservableCollection<Book>(x))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply do not have an observable collection bound to your grid.

in this line

```
var teamGroups = booksList.BooksDetail.GroupBy(team => team.BookCategory)
                                       .OrderBy(team => team.Key.ToString());
```

you create a linq statement that wraps your observable collection and exposes `IOrderedEnumerable` which you bind to your view. And this interface obviously does not forward change events from your collection and your property.

To solve this you need to hold in your `BooksDetails` (or any other property in your view model) `ObservableCollection` that is already sorted and grouped and bind it directly in xaml.  Setting source in this maner:

```
this.groupedItemsViewSource.Source = booksList.BooksDetail;
```

will not allow grid to recreate it self when `BooksDetail` property is changed.

---

```
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<Key, ObservableCollection<Book>>>(
          teamGroups.Select(x=>Tuple.Create(x.Key, 
                                            new ObservableCollection<Book>(x))));
```

If you want to crate second property note that you will have to synchronize them when books are added, deleted or have category changed.

Comment: So you mean that I need to create a separate Collection for this. So can you suggest a way to convert this IOrderedEnumerable to an ObservableCollection of <Key, ObservableCollection<Book>>?

Comment: Thanks... but I am facing some issue with binding to listview. I have added the updated code above. Can you please update me on this?